# Three.js giving a black screen, despite no console errors

Tags: javascript, json, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to put this 3D model onto the page, and set it up so the user's mouse will either move the model around the scene, or move the camera around the model so we see it from different angles. To do this I've tried using orbit controls.

I can get the model to appear static on the page. However, when I try to tweak the code and use orbit controls to get some movement happening I just get a black screen. There are no errors in the console.

Here's the code:

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
    
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
            HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
        camera.position.set(0,6,0);
        scene.add(camera);
    
        var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff); // white light
        scene.add(light);
    
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
        renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    
        var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        controls.addEventListener( 'change', function() { renderer.render(scene, 
        camera); } );
    
        <title>three.js</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="generator" content="Three.js Editor">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, 
        minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
            <style>
                body {
                    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    background-color: #000;
                    margin: 0px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }
                #edit {
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: 20px;
                    right: 20px;
                    padding: 8px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    color: #555;
                    opacity: 0.5;
                }
                #edit:hover {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body ontouchstart="">
            <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/app.js"></script>
            
            <script>
    
                var loader = new THREE.FileLoader();
                loader.load( 'app.json', function ( text ) {
    
                    var player = new APP.Player();
                    player.load( JSON.parse( text ) );
                    player.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                    player.play();
    
    
    
         window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
          var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
              HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
          renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
          camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
          camera.updateProjectionMatrix();          
    
        } )
    
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
            HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
        renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
        camera.position.set(0,6,0);
        scene.add(camera);
    
        controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        
        document.body.appendChild( player.dom );
    
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', function () {
        player.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                    } );
    
                    if ( location.search === '?edit' ) {
                        var button = document.createElement( 'a' );
                        button.id = 'edit';
                        button.href = 'https://threejs.org/editor/#file=' + 
         location.href.split( '/' ).slice( 0, - 1 ).join( '/' ) + '/app.json';
                        button.target = '_blank';
                        button.textContent = 'EDIT';
                        document.body.appendChild( button );
                    }
    
                } );
    
            
         OrbitControls = function ( object, domElement ) {
    
        this.object = object;
    
        this.domElement = ( domElement !== undefined ) ? domElement : document;
    
        // Set to false to disable this control
        this.enabled = true;
    
        // "target" sets the location of focus, where the object orbits around
        this.target = new THREE.Vector3();
    
        // How far you can dolly in and out ( PerspectiveCamera only )
        this.minDistance = 0;
        this.maxDistance = Infinity;
    
        // How far you can zoom in and out ( OrthographicCamera only )
        this.minZoom = 0;
        this.maxZoom = Infinity;
    
        // How far you can orbit vertically, upper and lower limits.
        // Range is 0 to Math.PI radians.
        this.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
        this.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI; // radians
    
        // How far you can orbit horizontally, upper and lower limits.
        // If set, must be a sub-interval of the interval [ - Math.PI, Math.PI ].
        this.minAzimuthAngle = - Infinity; // radians
        this.maxAzimuthAngle = Infinity; // radians
    
    
        // Set to false to disable rotating
        this.enableRotate = true;
        this.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
    
        } ;
    
        function handleMouseDownRotate( event ) {
    
            //console.log( 'handleMouseDownRotate' );
    
            rotateStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );
    
        }
    
        function handleMouseDownDolly( event ) {
    
            //console.log( 'handleMouseDownDolly' );
    
            dollyStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );
    
        }
    
        function handleMouseDownPan( event ) {
    
            //console.log( 'handleMouseDownPan' );
    
            panStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );
    
        }
    
        </script>
        
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: JavaScript inside the HTML head looks weird.

Comment: @SeregPie thanks, in what way do you mean it looks weird?

Comment: he means JavaScript should be inside `<script>` tags.

Comment: but also, put it at the end of the body, not the head.